# Prevent route change on refresh with Vue navigation guards

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have navigation guards working perfectly based on a `userTp` value, however whenever the user reloads a page it redirects them to `name: 'login'`.

I would like to prevent a route change on refresh. Is there a simple way to do this within navigation guards?

```js
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.requireAuth) {
    if (!store.state.auth.user) {
      await store.dispatch(AUTH_REFRESH)
    }
    if (to.meta.userTp === store.state.auth.user.userTp) {
      next()
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    } else {
      next({ name: 'login' })
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }
  } else {
    next()
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }
})
```

EDIT:

I found a semi-workaround for this, but it's not perfect. It allows users to access pages if they know the correct page url path, but since my setup has a server-side userTp check before sending data it just shows the page template but without any data in it.

My temp solution:
(Added as the first if statement)

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
      if (to = from) {
        if (!store.state.auth.user) {
          await store.dispatch(AUTH_REFRESH)
          to()
        }
      }
```

Comment: Is that code what you've been trying so far?

Comment: This sets up route guards based on userTp. I'm not sure where to add logic that will prevent a page change on browser refresh.

Comment: I've considered using localStorage to save the userTp when a user logs in, then checking routes based on that instead of the $store (since that persists on refresh and the store doesn't), but am not sure this is a best-practice due to security concerns. This is a small-scale app used by very few people, so I'm not too concerned about security, however I'd like to know the way other developers get around this issue.

Comment: Also, in my code above, I've set it to refresh the auth state if the route requires a specific userTp. This seems like it would work on refresh as well, however It's not awaiting this and simply sending the user back to login. Perhaps this is because it is using next() when no next() exists?